# mdframed doesn't break, but there are suffisant space for breakable mdframed

Tags: mdframed, picins

Here is the (almost)  MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25in,vmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{picins}

% fix for a bug that adds space after each paragraph with `parpic` of **picins**. It is then necessary to add `\killpic` after the first paragraph (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281949/how-to-prevent-parpic-from-cutting-into-every-paragraph-inside-a-proof-environm?rq=1)
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\killpic}{%
  \hangindent=0pt
  \let\par=\old@par
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 

\newcommand{\lipsumA}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue.}

\newcommand{\lipsumB}{Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.}

\newcommand{\logo}{\fbox{\huge{Logo}}}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray!20,linecolor=none,leftmargin=-10pt,rightmargin=-10pt]\parpic{\logo}\noindent \ignorespaces% \ignorespace is necessary, unless it, a space is added between logo and text
}{%
\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\lipsumA 

\begin{myenv}
    \lipsumA 
    
    \killpic
    
    \lipsumB
\end{myenv}

\lipsumA

\begin{myenv}
    \lipsumA 
    
    \killpic
    
    \lipsumB
    
    \lipsumA
    
    \lipsumB
    
    \lipsumA
    
    \lipsumB

\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Without `\parpic` from **picins**, there is no bug. But I need `\parpic` from **picins** (note that **picins** is not in TeXlive, but available on CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/picins); manually installed here on my computer: `~/textmf/tex/latex/picins/pincins.sty`).

Result :

[image: result]

How can the second mdframed begins in the first page, as there are suffisant space?

Comment: Try tcolorbox instead. Its breakable library is much better (but code like your picins which change the parshape can be quite tricky to use).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, this can be an alternative to consider if **picins** is really needed. I was unaware of the lettrine package alternative with a non external image, as exposed by marijn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative using `lettrine` instead of `picins`. Normally `lettrine` is used for a big capital letter spanning multiple lines vertically at the start of a paragraph followed by smallcaps. However, there is also an `image=true` key that is intended to add an image (that is passed on to `\includegraphics`). This option skips the processing of the large capital letter and is therefore suitable to insert other material. This becomes more flexible once you redefine the relevant `\LettrineImage` command to remove also the `\includegraphics` part.

The smallcaps can be skipped by leaving the second argument to `\lettrine` empty.

In the code below the logo image is raised a bit using the `lraise` key from `lettrine`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25in,vmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 

\newcommand{\lipsumA}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue.}

\newcommand{\lipsumB}{Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.}

\newcommand{\logo}{\fbox{\huge{Logo}}}

\renewcommand*{\LettrineImage}{%
\LettrineFontHook\relax%
}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray!20,linecolor=none,leftmargin=-10pt,rightmargin=-10pt]%
  \lettrine[image=true,lraise=0.2]{\logo\quad}{}%
}{%
\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\lipsumA 

\begin{myenv}
    \lipsumA 
    
    \lipsumB
\end{myenv}

\lipsumA

\begin{myenv}
    \lipsumA 
    
    \lipsumB
    
    \lipsumA
    
    \lipsumB
    
    \lipsumA
    
    \lipsumB

\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I have suppressed the `\quad` in the lettrine, added `nindent=0pt` in the lettrine option, and `\ignorespaces` after the lettrine (so the first character is right after the logo, without space), so I can adapt the space between the logo and the text by simply adding for exemple `\hspace` in the `\logo` code. Your code hase the advantage of not need the `\killpic`hack. I will wait if there are anothers solutions before select the better answer, but your are yet the favourite;).